# Scheduling a repeated HTTP request using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

In my Node application, I need to schedule a weekly API request to fetch some data from a third party website. I have 1000s of users who have multiple schedules set up in their accounts.

I was able to write a repeated schedule function using [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). But as the application scales and the number of users increase I don't think Cronjobs are a better way to solve this.

Are there any other alternatives to achieve my end goal?

Comment: which database you are currently using?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB

Comment: Okay. fine. Have you ever tried agenda for scheduling API ?

Comment: No, could you share any link which will guide me.

Comment: Yes. [https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda.

Answer (score 3):

This is an open-ended question, but let me suggest some potential design approaches.

Assuming you have many Users, each User has many Schedules, and each Schedule has a time spec (cron format, or whatever): store with each Schedule the last time the Schedule ran. Create a single "job" (a task, a program, etc.) that, when run, loops through all of your Users and evaluates their Schedules: for each Schedule, use the last time run and their time spec to calculate the next scheduled time to run, and if the current time is at or past that time, add the Schedule to a list. Then loop through the list, running each Schedule (whatever that entails), and updating the last run time.

By constructing your job this way, you can opt to use cron or not. You can run this program manually once a day, you can schedule it to run every 60 seconds on your primary application server (presumably for many runs it will exit without doing anything, as no more users have schedules that need to run yet). I think system cron is still useful for scheduling this type of task, but that's up to you.

At scale (let's say, you end up with 100,000 Users with 1-5 Schedules each), I would suggest a job-based queueing system. Using something like [node-resque](https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque), you could use cron to kick off a *schedule checker job* every 5 minutes, which would add individual *run schedule jobs* for each Schedule that needed to run. Eventually you'll have too many Users to evaluate in a single schedule checker; the *schedule checker job* could be modified to just count your Users, shard them, and kick off smaller *schedule checker jobs* (one for users 1-5000, one for users 5001-10000, etc. etc.). This would allow you to scale out and take advantage of 5 or 10 or 15 resque workers.

(I suggested resque as I'm a fan of redis, but you could just as easily use another queueing system or even, if you use Jenkins in your production, a series of Jenkins jobs that kick each other off and use Jenkins worker machines to run the jobs. That is the advantage of structuring your runner in this way, you can map it onto pretty much any technology.)

You'll still have plenty of challenges to solve: if all of these calls are to one remote API, you'll have to detect and handle overloading the remote API and getting rate limit errors (this may affect just how big you decide to scale out, there's no point in supporting 1,000 requests a second to the remote server if it will cap you at 5 requests a second). You'll also want to think about what happens if something breaks and you don't run jobs for a few hours (depending on your application, do you want your user's schedules to "catch up" and run later than intended for each scheduled run, or should it "skip ahead" to the latest time and ignore the lost time). Other nuances include schedules being deleted, or changed by the user while they in the run queue, etc.

Good luck!